# JPA: "Bad type on operand stack in arraylength"

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish

I'm trying to deploy a webapp in glassfish with the following entity managed by JPA. In the database, an **array of int** is stored in a **varchar**, and I split/join this String in the setter/getter

```
@Entity
public class MyClass
    implements Serializable
    {
    private long id;
    private int arrayofInt[];
    (...)

    private static String join(int array[])
        {
        StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();
        for(int i:array)
            {
            if(b.length()!=0) b.append(',');
            b.append(i);
            }
        return b.toString();
        }

    private static int[] split(String s)
        {
        String tokens[]=s.split("[,]");
        int array[]=new int[tokens.length];
        for(int i=0;i< tokens.length;++i)
            {
            array[i]=Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
            }
        return array;
        }

    @Column(name="fieldName")
    public String getArrayOfInt()
        {
        return join(arrayOfInt);
        }

    public void setArrayOfInt(String arrayOfInt)
        {
        this.arrayOfInt=split(arrayOfInt);
        }

    @Transient
    public int getCount()
        {
        return this.arrayOfInt.length;
        }
  (....)
  }
```

When my application is deployed in glassfish, I get the following error:

> remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while
>   preparing the app : Bad type on operand stack in arraylength in method
>   MyClass.getCount()I at offset 12345. Please see server.log for more
>   details. Command deploy failed.

if I replace getCount by

```
    @Transient
    public int getCount()
        {
        return 0,
        }
```

I get another new error:

> remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while
>   preparing the app : Bad type on operand stack in method
>   MyClass.getArrayOfInt()Ljava/lang/String; at offset 45678. Please see
>   server.log for more details. Command deploy failed.

how can I fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think this should be the setter, not the getter `public void getArrayOfInt(String arrayOfInt)`

Comment: It's a typo when I've simplified the code. I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the declaration of:

```
 private int arrayofInt[];
```

to

```
 private int _arrayofInt[];
 (...)
 public String getArrayOfInt()
        {
        return join(_arrayOfInt);
        }
```

and it works fine now... (?)